# Why are these macro definitions expanded so differently?

Tags: c, macros

```
#define INC1(a) ((a)+1)

#define INC2 (a) ((a)+1)

#define INC3( a ) (( a ) + 1)

#define INC4 ( a ) (( a ) + 1)
```

for above declaration in C language INC1 and INC3 works fine but INC2 and INC4 gives error, why ?

reference : https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/c-quiz-110-gq/  First Question

Comment: If you wanted `INC2` to expand to `(a) ((a)+1)`, how would you define it?

Comment: @Groo That is an insightful approach to answer the implicit "Why defined like that?"  Would you make an answer with it? Or maybe permit others to integrate this in their answers (It would make a nice addition to e.g. Somes answer.)

Comment: "but INC2 and INC4 gives error" I think I know what you mean, but it is guesswork. Would you like to demonstrate the error in a [mre]. Maybe have a look at the example use in my answer and explain what you expect and how it causes an error (probably in combination with some context code).

Comment: This is just how the syntax is, nothing exciting about it. The syntax for a function-like macro is `#define` _identifier_ _lparen_, where "identifier" is the macro name and "lparen" is defined as: "a `(` character not immediately preceded by white-space"

Comment: Try and see the output of just the preprocessor (for example `gcc -E ...`, [@godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/7x6Mqe))

Answer (score 4):

The syntax of function-like macros *requires* the opening parentheses to follow directly after the macro name, without any space between.

The preprocessor uses the space after the macro name to deduce when the macro-name ends and the body of the macro begins.

For example:

```
#define INC2 (a) ((a)+1)
```

This defines a *non* function-like macro, which expands to `(a) ((a)+1)`.

Comment: If it is used like `INC2(5)` it will be expanded to `(a) ((a)+1)(5)`, won't it?

Comment: @Yunnosch Yes it should.

Answer (score 1):

Please take this as an example-extension to the answer by Some programmer dude.

With your definitions, this piece of code...

```
INC1(10)
INC2(20)
INC3(30)
INC4(40)
```

will expand to ...

```
((10)+1)
(a) ((a)+1)(20)
(( 30 ) + 1)
( a ) (( a ) + 1)(40)
```

I guess now the question arises "Why is the presence of the whitespace so important?"
The answer to that is implied in an insightful way in the comment by Groo *(I hope they permit me using and elaborating here.)*

Assume that you actually want a macro to be expanded to something like `( a ) (( a ) + 1)`.  How would you do that, if these two definitions were treated identically?

```
#define INC1(a) ((a)+1)
#define INC2 (a) ((a)+1)
```

And would be expanded to

```
((10)+1)
((20)+1)
```

The difference between

```
INC(x) ...
INC (x) ...
```

makes that possible in a kind-of-intuitive way. Once you are aware of the problem.